# How to set JS effects on progress bar managed by a backing bean?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf, primefaces

I have

```
<h:form id="form">
    <p:progressBar id="pbAjax" value="#{backingBean.value}" labelTemplate="{value} %"/>
    <p:poll listener="#{backingBean.updateValue()}" update="pbAjax"/>
</h:form>
```

And

```
@ManagedBean
public class BackingBean implements Serializable {
    private Integer value;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        this.value = (int)Math.round(Math.random()*10);    
    }

    public Integer getValue(){
        this.value = (int)Math.round(Math.random()*10);    
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(Integer value){
        this.value = value;
    }

    public void updateValue(){
        this.value = (int)Math.round(Math.random()*5);
    }
}
```

The progress bar is working fine.

Now I would like to implement a "ease-in" effect. 
Since the values change with Ajax requests on a backing bean and not a Javascript function, how can I put a javascript effect on the progress bar, or "intercept" the XHR response to apply a "ease-in" effect in Javascript before it updates the component?

If it can help, I see this kind of Ajax response :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<partial-response id="j_id1">
    <changes>
        <update id="form:j_idt40:18:pbAjax">
            <![CDATA[
                <div id="form:j_idt40:18:pbAjax" class="ui-progressbar ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
                    <div class="ui-progressbar-value ui-widget-header ui-corner-all" style="display:block;width:9%">
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui-progressbar-label" style="display:block">
                        9 %
                    </div>
                </div>
                <script id="form:j_idt40:18:pbAjax_s" type="text/javascript">
                    $(function() PrimeFaces.cw(
                        "ProgressBar",
                        "widget_form_j_idt40_18_pbAjax",    
                            {
                                id:"form:j_idt40:18:pbAjax",
                                initialValue:6,
                                ajax:false,
                                labelTemplate:"{value} %"
                             }
                         );
                     });
                </script>
            ]]>
        </update>
        <update id="j_id1:javax.faces.ViewState:0">
            <![CDATA[-1946172786751610988:-1619424769397867671]]>
        </update>
    </changes>
</partial-response>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Look at the progressbar js in the source of PrimeFaces in github and try to create a solution from there. To 'complex' and specific for me to actually spend a fair amount of time on this and provide you with an answer (since in my opinion not a lot of other people are interested in this)... sorry.

Comment: In fact, without changing anything to PrimeFaces, I could actually implement a XHR listener in Javascript, then it could be maybe easier to rework the XHR response, like a Servlet. Never did it though.

Comment: I did not say you should change things to PrimeFaces, but you can override things... Just **learn** from the code what happens. Implementing an XHR listener might be to late (or you do it in an 'override PrimeFaces' way).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the setup shown above, the following solution works.

1. I've set the "update" method to static in my Managed Bean.

   ```
   public static Integer updateValue(){
       return (int)Math.round(Math.random()*5);
   }
   ```
2. Created a servlet with the content of my static method in the response body.

   ```
   @WebServlet(name = "ProgressBarServlet", urlPatterns = ("/ProgressBarServlet"})
   public class ProgressBarServlet extends HttpServlet {

   protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
   throws ServletException, IOException {
       response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
       response.setHeader("ProgressBarUpdate", "no-cache");
       PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
       out.print(BackingBean.updateValue()+"");
   }

   @Override
   protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
       throws ServletException, IOException {
       processRequest(request, response);
   }
   ```
3. Created a cyclic XHR request on the servlet url.

   ```
    <script type="text/javascript">
           setInterval(function () {
                   testAjax("ProgressBarServlet");
           }, 5000);

           function testAjax(servletURL) {
                   var xmlhttp;
                   if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                       xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                   }
                   else {
                       xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                   }
                   xmlhttp.open("GET", servletURL, true);
                   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                       if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4) { 
                           if (xmlhttp.status === 200) {
                               PF('pbAjax').setValue(xmlhttp.responseText);
                           }    
                           else {
                               PF('pbAjax').setValue("Error");
                           }
                       }
                   };
                   xmlhttp.send(null);
            }
   </script>
   ```

So the value of the progress bar is set with PrimeFaces Javascript and has the ease-in effect.

Albeit it might not be the most efficient way to update components, this solution can be useful for one or few components.

It is not relevant in my case, because I have a p:dataTable with a progress bar in each row and cannot link generated ids to Javascript.